# link inside an iframe that refers an anchor in the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a HTML page with the following structure:

index.html has a menu at the top, where if the user clicks stuff its loaded into an iframe at the bottom (the iframe auto resizes with JS if the content is loaded.)

Now I want to place a "go to the top" link in some of the pages, that are in the iframe, but since the anchor is in index.html it does not work, e.g:

index.html:

```
    <body>
    <a name="topOfThePage"></a>
    ...
    <iframe ...
```

in the subpages, that get loaded into the iframe in index.html:

```
    <a href="#topOfThePage" >go to the top</a>
```

This does not seem to work, anyone knows how to do this? (without JS if possible)

Comment: I don't think you can do it without JS. The whole idea of IFRAMEs is that it's an independent browser context.

Comment: It was probably just a typo, but the name in the anchor shouldn't have a # on the start, that's only used for linking to it.

Comment: @Niall true, its a typo ive edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `target="_parent"` to the anchor.

Edit: This will target the parent frame, but it will use the location of the iframe's page, so the href actually needs to be e.g. index.html#topOfThePage if the iframe containing page is index.html. Obviously this will only work if the iframe content page is always going to be contained used in the same containing page - let me know if that's not the case, I'll think of something else.

Comment: That will load the target into the parent frame, but I don't think it will look for the ID in the parent DOM.

Comment: @Niall it does not seem to work, if I do this: <a href="index.html#topOfThePage" target="_parent" >go to the top</a> it works in Chrome, but IE 10 reloads index.html, thus the displayed iframe is lost.

Comment: Ah, unfortunate. Yeah, I only tried it in Chrome. I think you're going to need JavaScript then.